# AngularJS - access model from another directive

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, scope, angular-ngmodel

[Here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aQ21cfKOxRy35ocbZopR?p=preview).

How do I access the `headerInput` model from within the `sideMenuContent` directive? Let's say I have 10 other `ng-models` in `sideMenuHeader` directive that I want to access in `sideMenuContent`, is there any way of making it easily scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the dot notation for objects.  See [Understanding Scopes in AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

So instead of `headerInput`, use something like `menu.headerInput` and also make sure to initialize a `menu` object in your controller like so `$scope.menu = {};` (or you can also set default values).

[I updated your plunkr to show you how it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/El0A1sXHQ2FNDjOtaExH?p=preview)

Comment: Sweet, this works! It feels a tad ugly though (my fault). What do you think about all of my `ng-transclude`'s and stuff? I tried to create a boilerplate sideMenu-directive with sub-directives (header and content). Is there a better way of doing what I've tried to do?

Comment: I don't think that it's ugly, you are using `ng-transclude` for their intended functionality.  The only suggestion I would make is to not have your template all on one line or to separate it out into a `templateURL` so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Yeah I hate writing HTML as strings in JS, no matter the length of it. I did so on my plnkr because i was lazy :).